# dart: how to get correct (typed) reference to document object in iframe

Tags: dart, dart-html

I have a use case where a complex UI hierarchy needs to be rendered in an iframe, but the logic handling it (creation, enter document, event handling, exit document) need to be in the main frame / app.

I face issues with getting a typed reference to the Document instance of the iframe. Is this possible at all? The code errors even with type casts.

Any advise would be helpful, except the one to use js interop - something as simple as extracting a UI branch and fitting it inside an iframe should not require this IMHO.

Also if this is not possible where should I go filling a bug?

Comment: There are several related bugs. You didn't provide any code which shows what you actually tried nor any error message therefore it's hard to tell what exactly applies. The main cause is that the Dart team tried to secure cross window access and now this is in a state where it just can't be used.
See http://dartbug.com/20944, http://dartbug.com/20146, http://dartbug.com/20173, http://dartbug.com/20174, http://dartbug.com/16814, (closed, just for reference http://dartbug.com/2312, http://dartbug.com/1928) and several more (search for _DOMWindowCrossFrame)

Comment: I am simply trying to obtain reference to the html.Document in the iframe and would like to use it as html.document would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross window access is very limited due to security concerns. There are open issues to allow it again because it can be circumvented by dart-js-interop anyway.

So the suggested solution is to use `dart:js` as workaround until the issues are fixed.

```dart
  var ifrm = new js.JsObject.fromBrowserObject(dom.querySelector('#ifrm'));
  print(ifrm['contentWindow']);
  print(ifrm['contentDocument']);
```

Comment: I am currently trying it with dart:js and it is still not working (js.context['window']['frameid'] is not allowed either... how do I do this?

Comment: What about `js.context('window'].['frames'][0])`?

Comment: I dont get it, does not seem like a valid dart expression at all, also it seems Dart figures out that the result of content[frames][index] is an IframeElement and does not allow access with []: Class 'IFrameElement' has no instance method '[]'.

Comment: Thank, so how would I use this 'HTMLDocument' as dart html.Document? Currently it still thinks it is a JsObject?

Comment: I don't think you can get a typed/Dart object from this JsObject. As far as I know all you can do is interact with it using dart-js-interop.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `window.postMessage()` to transfer DOM updates between the frames. That might be a possiblity I guess?

Comment: It is an option, but the overhead is much bigger and is not suitable for syncing with RAF.